# Should desktop applications silently update?

Tags: security, language-agnostic

Lots of programs silently update, notably Chrome, which must always silently update, but most operating systems can be set to silently update, and many other programs can as well, though it is not often the default and even less often is it mandatory.

But, I have created programs that silently update myself, and had complaints about security issues. So, do you think that programs should

- Be forced to silently update?
- Optionally silently update, with silent updating being the default?
- Optionally silently update, with silent updating not being the default?

And what are the potential security issues with a silently updating program?

Comment: Dropbox (http://db.tt/jnYosez) does it, and it's just a fantastic feature!

Comment: @balexandre: I use Dropbox. My experience of it is no better or worse now than it was before they introduced auto-update. So it's not a "fantastic feature", it's a nearly-neutral feature with a small but unnecessary risk of something incredibly annoying in future (like pwning a room full of PCs at once, if there's any exploitable flaw in the update mechanism, or pushing a buggy version to the whole world). If it was optional, then those interested in small risks could make a decision.

Comment: I was always checking up the versions, in work PC I had one version, in my home another, and I was always verifying what's the diff, how can I update to the latest, etc, afraid that the non-last version could be out-of-sync one time or not to update an important file. Luckily I only have one Mac. Now, those days are gone. As I mention before, this is a question that will always have plenty of answers and none will be right. Hence the close vote from my part.

Comment: @balexandre: I don't see what that has to do with *compulsory silent* updates. Dropbox used to not auto-update at all IIRC, I don't mind auto-checking for updates. If they weren't compulsory, that would still solve all your problems, naturally you'd configure "always update immediately". If they weren't silent, that would still solve your worrying about different versions, although you would see updates occurring, which unlike me you don't want. I want us both to be happy: you want you to be happy and me to be unhappy. This is the difference between configurable and non-configurable behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think programs being forced to silently update is out of the question. In a high-security environment where software is audited, your "update" is an attempt to introduce unknown code to the environment without permission, hence is automatically treated as malicious. It only takes a small number of users who consider your software malicious to constitute a problem.

Even in a less uptight environment, I think it's antisocial to deny your users the ability to delay updates for their own reasons. I could speculate what those reasons are: for example they might rely on some behavior of the old version, but the basic point is that the reasons are *your users' reasons*, not yours. You don't get to know what they are, so if you respect your users in the slightest degree, you can't force them to change the software on their machine just because you think the new version is better.

That said, update by default is probably a good idea at the moment. Windows in particular has decided, over the last 15 years or so since it has been really feasible, not to introduce any kind of integrated update management for applications. The result is a terrible mess of intrusive software update strategies, and the least intrusive strategy available seems to me to be:

1. check for updates when the software starts up (and periodically while it is running), *not* all the time in some unkillable background process.
2. install updates silently unless the user has said they're interested in updates, in which case tell them about the update and (if they've said they want to be asked) ask them whether to install it or not.
3. Provide the user with an easy means to check the update history.

A checked-by-default checkbox at install time, "look for and install all updates in future", would seem to me to be adequate permission, but consult your own lawyer.

In security terms, if your update procedure is really secure then your silent update procedure will be too. So if we're willing to assume perfection there's no difference.

*However*, if the user doesn't trust your update procedure, then they might not want to take updates when they're on e.g. an insecure wireless network, because they might be concerned e.g. that somebody has obtained a fake SSL certificate for your domain. Obviously MITM attacks can be performed on networks other than insecure wireless networks, but they certainly are far more common in that case, so the risk is higher. Silent updating prevents the user from managing that risk in a way they're comfortable with, instead it's managed in a way that you (the software author) is comfortable with. You have to think about whose comfort is more important, and again that's about what kind of respect you have for your users.

The first person whose silent software update gets subverted at a Black Hat conference, thereby pwning every machine in the room foolish enough to have their software installed, will get precisely the coverage they deserve in the tech press.

Comment: I would not agree, Dropbox does this in a fantastic manner, if it's a **service app**, it should get auto-silent-updates, everything else, I would prefer as Paint.NET, ask first, install later.

Comment: @balexandre: Dropbox says, (http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=24046) "*Unfortunately* [disabling auto-update] is not possible at this time". My emphasis, and I entirely agree with that Dropbox employee, it's deeply regrettable. Dropbox does not respect its users' opinions, it's confident that it knows better than they do what software they should run. If the Paint.NET people were equally confident, it would do exactly the same, doesn't matter what you want. But then, Dropbox has a lot of free users that directly cost it money in Amazon cloud fees, so what should they expect?

Comment: There is a real issue with software that uses proprietary communication protocols, though. If Dropbox or Skype or WoW changes its protocols, then anyone who doesn't update the software might not be able to connect to the service any more. *Even so*, if the user honestly believes that lost service is preferable to installing unknown (to the user) code, IMO that's their business, not Dropbox's or Skype's (or MS's) or Blizzard's. The update could always come with a warning "would you like to install this? If you don't, you will have no Dropbox service once we disable the old protocol next week".

Answer (score 2):

Depends how you define silent update and what is the nature of the program... I'd kinda prefer if my anti-virii package silently updated, but if my sdk's started doing it, i would be a sad panda.

It may be a language-agnostic question, but it surely isn't an application-agnostic one.

Update:
Thinking more about it, its highly dependent on the service the application serves and what the nature and urgency of the update actually is.  Security hotfixes and virii definitions come to mind.

Even with all that said, in this day and age of mobile computing, I would frown upon any network activity by a program with zero user interaction/notification (or ability to delay it). I say that as a person who has had that certain OS (windows) silently download a service pack (well over 100 megs) while I was tethered to my cell phone on 3g that cost me almost 30 dollars in overages.

Keeping in line with this 'user first' attitude-- I struggle to find a legitimate reason to perform silent updates when the alternative of a background update gets the same job done, keeps the user informed, and doesn't step on anyones toes

Comment: With SDKs the developers of the SDK have to be more careful that they remain backwards compatible, but assuming that they do stay backwards compatible, then would you want them to silently update?

Comment: @Drew: I still wouldn't want them to silently update. Even if they maintain compatibility, I might want to pin a particular version of the SDK for some purpose -- because of known buggy behavior in that version of the SDK; in order to precisely reproduce a build; paranoia about the risk of new bugs in new versions; because despite backward compatibility, the code I'm compiling incorrectly relies on undocumented behavior of the old, breaks in the new, and I can't fix it (yet). In all those circumstances I need to disable/refuse updates.

Comment: @colinross: already gave you +1, which is a shame because I'd like to +1 you for the concrete example of installing updates over an expensive connection. In theory at least, Chrome's updates are tiny and so if you're using it at all, you might as well take the update for all the difference it makes to bandwidth. In practice, software vendors can be deeply unimaginative about how their antics will affect their customers ;-)

Comment: @Steve: keeping programs that rely on buggy and undocumented behaviour from breaking is part of backwards compatibility. Its would be quite difficult, and maybe in the case of SDKs it might even be impossible, but if it was possible, would it be desireable?

Comment: @Drew: typically, preserving undocumented behavior is *not* part of backward-compatibility, that's why it's undocumented, so that it can change in future without breaking compatibility. Sometimes vendors will go some way to preserving undocumented behavior if they know that people are relying on it, but that's by introducing a new guarantee. The only way to preserve *all* behavior is to make no changes at all, so in that case sure, if there were never any updates then it would be fine for updates to be inconvenient ;-) SDK updates also are likely to be large (see colinross's point about 3G)

Comment: +1 for exactly what Steve said. If you're thinking of silent updates, you should either (1) have them off by default, (2) find a way of detecting if it's safe to use the user's bandwidth - this depends not just on if the line is metered, but also potentially whether it has limited capacity and other higher-priority users, so it's very hard to determine, or (3) use an advanced binary-diff system like Google does to make the updates tiny. Personally I think (3) is the best idea.

Comment: Developers may think it a neat trick (silent background updates), but really-- what is the harm in a heads up to the user that you'll be updating stuff in the background?  I would never want to leave the decision of how hard to step on the user's toes up to a programatic algorithm like #2 option above.

Comment: The harm in a heads up to the users is most users (even myself, a software developer) find it annoying.  Most of the time I couldn't care less whether an application updates or not but for some reason developers think it is acceptable to endlessly pester their users about updates.

Answer (score 2):

Whether a progrm should silently update depends upon application and the users.  As for the security risk, there are basically two risks: most obviously from the users perspective the updated application isn't the old application and may change a behavior they like or depend on or simply not work on their computer at all.  Secondly, the actual security concern is that the the update process might be subverted, in which case your update is a trojan.

Answer (score 1):

Some users (me, for example) get annoyed when something is done to their computer without their permission. So, whatever you do, get the user's permission before doing auto-updates, and let the user switch the auto-updates off at any time.

Comment: This is a valid concern, however I would hazard a guess that the number or people who are annoyed by things being done to their computer without their permission is less then the number of people who get annoyed by having to explicitly update their software. And the less people I annoy, then better.

Answer (score 1):

There is always 2 sides of this and options will diverge.

I would try to simplify things:

Is it an application that we really don't care about versions, that the latest is always the best to use?

Then simply make the app to do this **automagically**.

*Applications that IMHO should have this:*

- Any **service application** (the one that runs in the clock area and we just use it and really don't care that much about versioning)
- **Anti Virus** (we really want to be up-to-date, and dont want to update the virus definitions every day/week)
- FTP Client
- Virtual Machines Tools
- etc...

---

Is is **everything else**, do as [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) does:

[image]

or some Mac apps

[image]

*Applications that IMHO should have this:*

- CRM, ERP, etc (we should never mess up here, plenty of customers could have plugins for an exact version)
- Browsers (you never want IE8 to be automatically changed to IE9)
- Developer Tools
- etc.

Comment: I don't agree. I don't share your view that one "doesn't care" about the version of an FTP client, but "does care" about the version of an HTTP client. So I want to be able to decide which applications on my machine "automagically" update, because I know what I care about, and you don't know. But you want to deny me that choice for applications that IYHO should silently auto-update. Why do you care whether I have the latest FTP client anyway? How do you even know it's the best, maybe it has some stupid bug in it that I read about on the internet and don't want to install.

Comment: why won't you? me as a developer, if my users can have a better polish app, I would certain push it automagically. can be a major bug that, f.ex. you didn't even notice, but some might... could be a small issue, a typo... would be better to push it. Then again, it's only my opinion :)

Comment: And on the subject of Antivirus - a few months ago I took an A/V update that slowed down my machine's boot-to-desktop time by about a minute. I've eaten that, but other users might well have preferred to stick with the old version while they found a better product. I get that software vendors want to hide flaws in their products behind "it's inevitable, you need the new version". I just don't think it's admirable, or should be recommended.

Comment: @balexandre: the main reason I wouldn't is if the bug only affects certain uses, and I'm one of those uses. So if you've automagically pushed me the update, I can't FTP to my unusual server until you push *another* fix. If you'd let me choose, I could skip the broken version and update once the issue's resolved. But in general, users prefer to do things *for reasons that you, the software vendor, do not know and cannot predict*. The arrogance that says, "I know what FTP client you need" could equally say, "I know what version of IE you need", and then *you're* an unhappy user too.

Comment: You are doing something that I think it's wrong, you are assuming that an update will be broken. It can happen, but it's like the UpTime Hosting, 99,9% will not be broken and I'm taken that unit tests, UI tests and installation tests would be made prior to push such things.

Comment: @balexandre: no, I'm assuming that someday an update will be wrong. This assumption is correct, eventually some update *will* be broken, although it's not certain that the brokenness will affect me. If I'm lucky enough to find out about it before I've installed it, and can stop it installing, then I win.

Comment: Anyway, even if your software is perfect (which it isn't), the more general point is that anyone working in a locked-down environment, by choice or by employer policy, possibly can't use your software at all and certainly won't get your silent updates. Or if your software is open-source, they could fork it to strip out the misfeature.

Comment: "(you never want IE8 to be automatically changed to IE9)" I disagree, Chrome updates automagically and I prefer it that way, and a majority of the people I've spoken to that use it prefer it that way as well.